# Only seeing one line of text in the textblock element when creating a windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create a windows phone app with lots of texts like this text here under, but it either gets chopped or gets only on 1 line. I have tried different solutions of scrollable textblock and etc but nothing seems to work. The text I want to post in the app is around 30000 characters long.

Comment: 30,000 characters? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6603109/241631) might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the [TextWrapping property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.textwrapping%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to `wrap`.

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Also make sure you don't constrain the TextBlock in terms of height.

Comment: It still gets chopped after 4/30 of the text but i made scrolling and everything else thanks to u?

Comment: Anyone else wanna complete his answer it still chops the text after like 400 lines of text

Comment: All UI elements are limited to 2048x2048px in WP7 (and Silverlight, I think).  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602544/how-many-characters-can-a-silverlight-textblock-hold

Comment: Thanks:) I created a RSS feed reader object which solved this

Answer (score 0):

I created a RSS reader page within the wp application which solved my issue of text being chopped. My intent with this app was to integrate some info about my clients company.

Regards Joel