# Windows Phone : Text in textblock not showing fully

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, textblock

**Problem solved!
Anyway, I just figured out the problem. I did a .Trim() on the values and surprisingly they can be wrapped. Thanks and sorry for all the trouble. =)**

I am doing some data binding to my textblock in a grid.

However, some of the texts are not showing fully. 
[image: Error]

I tried the Text Wrapping and setting a maximum width to my textblock. But none of them worked.

**EDIT : Hi again. I noticed that when I changed the text of the textblock manually via codes like**

```
 txtDesc.Text = "This is a job for Stackers. If you like stacking, please contact me.
```

**The text wrapping actually works. So somehow the databind result text can't be wrap?**

The XAML code for my textblock.

```
 <TextBlock Name="Description"  Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="     {StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Height="auto" Width="220" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="220"></TextBlock>
```

Any help here?

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="images/SmallLogoNTitle.png"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <toolkit:ListPicker ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="lpkTypeOfService" Margin="0,116,12,0" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="210" SelectionChanged="lpkTypeOfService_SelectionChanged">

            </toolkit:ListPicker>
            <ListBox Margin="8,210,8,26" Name="listBox1" Width="450">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="Date" Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment= "Left" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Name="Creator" Text="{Binding CreatorID}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="Type" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="Amount" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Amount}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Name="Description"  Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Height="auto" Width="220" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxWidth="220"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Content="Apply" Height="70" Width="140" Name="btn1" Click="btn_Click" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            <TextBlock Height="65" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,116,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Find Service :" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="216" FontSize="36" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you try to remove Height="auto" and your MaxWidth?

Comment: Hi there. I removed Height="auto" and MaxWidth. It's still not working. =(

Comment: I have written an answer that addresses this situation: [StackFlow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40022535/2768516)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from poor / over-complicated layout architecture and the way your objects are positioning each other. Might try something like this for your `DataTemplate`

```
    <DataTemplate>

       <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
             <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!-- Don't worry, you already had your 450 Width set on the parent -->
             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

             <TextBlock Name="Date" Text="{Binding Date}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
             <TextBlock Name="Creator" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CreatorID}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
             <TextBlock Name="Type" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Type}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
             <TextBlock Name="Amount" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Amount}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
             <TextBlock Name="Description" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
             <Button Name="btn1" Click="btn_Click" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Content="Apply" Height="70" Width="140" Margin="5,0"/>

          </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
```

Also for the sake of cleaner xaml, remember things like `Margin="0"`, `Grid.Column="0"`, `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` etc. are default dependency properties, so no need to set them to each individual object. Even in the case you need to, you can apply them as `Setter`s to the `TargetType` in the parent `Object.Resources` and avoid setting them to each individual object. Another tip would be, don't rely on a bunch of obfuscated random Margins etc to create your layout. It's best to do it right the first time instead of hunting down discrepancies between a bunch of inter-dependent little "fixes"

I didn't test it, but should work fine unless you got something else somewhere pushing stuff around. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there. I just tried your code. It did not work. Look at my updated comments in bold above. I believe that the databinded text can't be textwrap for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you by chance reading them from another file you're parsing that's preserving the white-space in the string? Something like an XML file with say, `line xml:space="preserve"` for example?

Comment: Hi there. I am reading the values from a database. Anyway, I just figured out the problem. I did a .Trim() on the values and surprisingly they can be wrapped. Thanks and sorry for all the trouble. =)

Comment: Well there you go, sometimes just need a little inspiration to look in another place for the problem. I would still suggest cleaning up the layout a bit though, glad you found your solution. :P

Answer (score 0):

Can you disable horizontal scrolling in your listbox control?

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

Comment: <ListBox Margin="8,210,8,26" Name="listBox1" Width="450" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >

Is this what you mean?
I did that and it did not work. =[

Comment: And if you replace this <RowDefinition Height="auto"/> by <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

Answer (score 0):

Use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` instead of `VerticalAlignment="Top"`. This way the textblock will stretch to the height of the row.

Comment: Hi. I changed to VerticalAlignment="Stretch" but it is still not working. 

 <TextBlock Name="Description"  Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"  Width="220" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>

Comment: Could you also add this to your listbox?
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter> 
    </Style> 
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

Comment: Where do I put it? Can I email you my source code? How do I pm you?

Comment: Put it right after <ListBox Margin="8,210,8,26" Name="listBox1" Width="450">

Comment: Hi again. I did that. But it is still not working. Any more solutions? =(

Comment: Just tried your XAML with a mock class that I've created and for me it works all right. Didn't change anything in the XAML. So maybe the issue is with your string. Maybe it contains some unwanted characters, some extra line breaks?

Comment: Anyway, I just figured out the problem. I did a .Trim() on the values and surprisingly they can be wrapped. Thanks and sorry for all the trouble. =)